# How to run tests asynchronously using pytest and gevent or another asynchronous approach?

Tags: asynchronous, pytest, gevent

I have a lot of tests that expose REST API using requests library.
All tests take a lot of time to finish. 
And I want to make them asynchronous, but I don't such experience.
Can someone help me with giving some advice or articles where I can find information about it? Or maybe you know another approach.

P.S: using xdist pytest plugin does not work for me, it does not start running my tests in parallel due to some reason that I don't know, not only me faced with this issue.